Expected parasitic draw on a 24V system (2 x 12V in series)
So, as per the title, I'm kind of wondering what the acceptable range of parasitic draw is on a 24V truck? Its got 2 12V batteries in series and I've had it die on me in 1 week after being charged to full.
Voltage over the combined unit is only 23.22V when its been left standing for about 1hr.
Measuring parasitic current draw only brings up about 70mA. Is there a better way to measure the parasitic draw other than by disconnected the negative wire and then probing between the negative wire and terminal?

Is it 24V to the starter only, and 12V to lights, engine and accessories? Is it just a single heavy cable that attaches one battery to the other (+ to -), and no other wires connected to the joined terminals? If you have other wires connecting where the batteries join, then it's a 12/24 system, and you must test for parasitic current from each battery separately.

If you are only getting just above 23vdc at the batteries after they've sat for a while, I'd suggest you get the batteries load tested. A "good" battery which is fully charged sits somewhere usually over 13vdc. Add two together and they should be over 26vdc. I'd suggest one or both batteries may be weak.

Tolerable current draw on 12 or 24 volts is going to be the same, the ampacity of two batteries in series is the same as one alone. As mentioned, that resting voltage is too low, it's likely that one or both batteries need replaced.

@MTA So, its a 24V system aka 2 x 12V batteries in series. Everything is powered from this, currently for my aftermarket 12V items, I've used a 24V-12V/20A voltage converter for stepping it down. To describe the layout its as such; 24V system through to existing vehicle electronics, additional 24V wiring to my converter (inline fuse of 25A), converter provides output 12V cabling and that is terminated into a busbar terminal block from which it feeds multiple outputs to inline fuses depending on the expected load after which its wiring to the units where they are mounted.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I see, I wasnt entirely aware of this  but that could probably be why. I just hope that its not the additional converter and 12V items that I've added which has caused this.

@user461193 Understood, so there are no wires of any kind attached at the join point between the two batteries that would drain only one battery. Now as stated above, it's best to perform a high amp load test on each of the batteries individually because it appears that one of your batteries has outlived its useful life.

@MTA I ended up doing this very thing. Turns out one of the batteries were indeed cooked and needed replacing. Since replacement and have left it sat for a good 3 or 4 days, it still starts fine and doesnt go completely flat with a total drain of 70mA on the battery.

@user461193 Great news, glad it worked out.

My mechanic just fixed a parasitic draw in my car last week while I watched him.  He connected his clamp ammeter to the positive pole of the battery, while the car was connected to the battery normally.  He did not disconnect the negative and connect the meter in series, as you are describing.  He found the culprit and fixed the drain on my battery.

That would absolutely short the battery and fuck up the car and him. I can almost gurantee that he was using the multimeter in the voltage setting and not reading for current. Since then I did find a handy guide given to me on reddit by a gentleman who mentioned that its easier to do a voltage drop test over the fuses which I was going to attempt today. This is the guide: https://www.autonerdz.com/yabbfiles/Attachments/HowtodoParasiticdraintestacrossfuses.pdf

I will not delete the post, but I did edit it because you are partly right.  The mechanic was likely using a clamp ammeter in DC mode, connecting it only to one terminal while the car was connected to the battery normally.

@Carguy Good edit, no longer a dangerous meter connection and the answer is fine now. The only issue is that a clamp DC ammeter that's sensitive enough to measure millamps of current is way more expensive than a simple multimeter. The technique described by the OP is valid, safe and much more sensitive and accurate than using a hobby-grade clamp ammeter. But if a person does have an expensive, pro quality clamp ammeter, there's no question that it will work and it's also easier than disconnecting the battery.

@MTA Thx for all the clarification!
